# How does one obtain the following algebraic expression?

Tags: calculus

Given the following expression:

$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial n} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \cos(\alpha) + \frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\sin(\alpha) $$

By differentiating the above expression w.r.t. $\alpha$ and setting the derivative to zero to get the maximum $\alpha$, one obtains:

$$\tan(\alpha_1) = \frac{\partial w/\partial y}{\partial w/\partial x}$$

I follow the above, but am having trouble beyond that:

Substituting for $\sin(\alpha_1)$ and $\cos(\alpha_1)$ into the first expression should give:

$$\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial n}\right)_{max} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right)^2} $$

How do they get that expression? Regardless of whether we manipulate the tan term to be in terms of sin or cos, there will always be terms in the denominator, which I cannot get rid of i.e. here is my attempt:

$\sin(\alpha_1) = \left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}/\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\right)\cos(\alpha_1)$ and $\cos(\alpha_1) = \left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}/\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right)\sin(\alpha_1)$

Then substituting into the first expression gives:

$\frac{\partial w}{\partial n} = \left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}/\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right)\sin\alpha_1 + \left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}/\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\right)\cos\alpha_1 $

Squaring both sides gives an extra term, so I can't go beyond this step. Please help.

Comment: Do we assume that the partial derivative of $\partial w / \partial x$ and $\partial w / \partial y$ w.r.t. $\alpha$ is 0?

Answer (score 2):

I think they just apply the standard rewriting 
$$
A\sin\alpha+B\cos\alpha=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\sin(\alpha+\delta)
$$
where the angle $\delta$ is a solution to $\cos\delta=\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$ and $\sin\delta=\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$. Clearly, the largest value of the expression is $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ (called the *amplitude*).